# Unity launcher doesn't hide automatically on start up

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

When you start an application, say, Firefox, the Launcher continues to be placed over it. This is cleared up by moving the mouse to the left edge of the screen and then away, but it shouldn't happen in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to determine, this behavior has been fixed since the release of 11.04 - I suggest that you keep your system up-to-date. (for more on that, [take a look at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56348/how-do-i-update-ubuntu/56349#56349))